# Learning Javascript - A Yes|No Macro based on clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may get hammered for this question because it's no doubt very basic Javascript. Please forgive the syntax, I want to see if my logic is right and if there is a better way.

I'm attempting to create a Macro. The Macro should return the button choice made by the visitor, either Yes or No. On the particular page in question the website visitor is asked to click one of two buttons: a Yes button or a No button. Here they are:

```
<footer>
    <button id="NoBtn">No</button>
    <button id="YesBtn" type="submit">Yes</button>
</footer>
```

Here's my attempt to create a Macro. I've no doubt there is a better way. Please tell me. I'd like to track which button the visitor clicks:

```
<script>

  var confirmChoice = "none"

  $('#NoBtn').click(function(event){
  confirmChoice = $(this).textContent;
  });
  $('#YesBtn').click(function(event){
  confirmChoice = $(this).textContent;
  });

  return confirmChoice

</script>
```

Is this "right"? Is my logic correct? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: 1) What do you consider to be a "macro"? 2) jQuery objects don't have a property `textContent`, that's a property of DOM elements. 3) You can only return from a function. What do you expect the `return` statement to do here?

Comment: since you suggest to forgive the syntax, I assume this is not working code? the `return` statement only works when inside a function, where something asks the function for data, and the function `return`s a result.  here, you aren't asking for the data, so where would it be used?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for following up. I would like the Macro to return either "Yes" or "No" depending on which button is clicked. If no button is clicked the Macro should return "none". OK re textContent, maybe I'll try innerHTML?

Comment: PS for context this Macro is being used with Google-Tag-Manager. This tool allows you to add scripts on the fly to reuse throughout your analytics tracking installation.

Comment: The purpose of the Macro is to return a string of either "Yes" or "No" depending on which of the two buttons the visitor clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be like this

```
var confirmChoice = 'none';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        confirmChoice = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

That way you can use a single event to track either click on your buttons and you return the text property of the button clicked.

Comment: "The JavaScript macro must contain a function with a return statement." This is what Tag-Manager told me when I tried that. So I added return confirmChoice, first before the last curly brace, then before the second last curly brace, then inside the function underneath ...text(); But I get an error message "Error at line 2, character 4: Parse error. primary expression expected."?

Comment: Here's what I tried that doesn't seem to be allowed or validated via the tag management tool:
$("#(No|Yes)Btn").click(function () {
    var btnChoice = ($(this).text()  );
    return btnChoice;
   });
Can you see anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way using css class, assuming you want to do it in less code.

The HTML

```
<footer>
   <button class="btnOption" id="NoBtn">No</button>
   <button class="btnOption" id="YesBtn" type="submit">Yes</button>
</footer>
```

The javascript

```
    $(".btnOption").click(function () {
    alert($(this).text()  );
   });
```

Comment: This will not be any use since the purpose of the tool I am using, assumes that you (The Analyst) has no control of the website html. If there was a way to write a regular expression such as $("#(No|Yes) Btn").click(function () { that could work. Is that possible?

Comment: Just tried that - "JavaScript Compiler Error YesNoButton1 (the Macro in question) Error at line 4, character 6: Parse error. ')' expected."

Comment: The answers that have been posted are valid answers to the initial question.   Can you modify your question and help explain in more details maybe not the code itself but rather the environment / limitations you are the intended user will be restricted to.

Comment: I managed to get this to "work" int hat the tool I'm using allows the code to pass. But it's not doing what I expected. That, however, is beyond the original scope of this question and will involve a bit of pocking around. Thanks for your answer all the same